# What is this sheet on a Super Étendard?

Tags: feature-identification, super-etendard

What is this sheet on a Super Étendard ?

[image]

As seen on

Comment: Don't worry, it's just [one sheet to the wind](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/three-sheets-to-the-wind.html). Joking aside, the first image very much looks like it's from a game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the port-side ventral airbrake, as can be seen in this diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an airbrake. there are both of them, each side of the ventral face. it moves with an hydraulic actuator

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE!

Comment: Well, he did mention the hydraulic actuator.